I have an error that is repeted many time in my thesis.tex "Missing number, treated as zero.<to be read again>"
I had used a thesis template on Overleaf and written on it. Everything was fine until I received a "compilation time out" error message asking me to upgrade to the paid version. So, I downloaded a website template and started compiling it. At first, everything seemed to be going well. I modified the preamble and integrated my introduction without any issues. However, as soon as I added my first chapter, a large number of errors occurred and repeated, such as:

Missing number, treated as zero.

! Improper alphabetic constant.<to be read again


I am attaching my preambule.tex file and my thesis.tex file, which is the main file, to this message.
Thank you for your assistance. I have been unable to make progress for a week.
preambule.tex
%% Encodings packages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Specify an input encoding UTF8
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % Font encodings
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
%% Math packages
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{makeidx}
%% Figures
\usepackage{graphicx}       % Including Graphics Files, delete the demo option if you want to include your owen Figs
\usepackage{epstopdf}       % adds support of handling eps images
\usepackage{float}          % Force the placement of Figs 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{pgf,pgfplots}
\usepackage{smartdiagram} 
\usepackage{rotating}\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,calc,matrix,arrows,shapes,positioning,shadows,shapes.arrows,trees,datavisualization.formats.functions,fit,calc}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[francais]{minitoc}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
%\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz/]
\newcommand{\boxplot}[6]{%
    %#1: center, #2: median, #3: 1/4 quartile, #4: 3/4 quartile, #5: min, #6: max
    \filldraw[fill=white,line width=0.2mm] let \n{boxxl}={#1-0.1}, \n{boxxr}={#1+0.1} in (axis cs:\n{boxxl},#3) rectangle (axis cs:\n{boxxr},#4);   % draw the box
    \draw[line width=0.2mm, color=red] let \n{boxxl}={#1-0.1}, \n{boxxr}={#1+0.1} in (axis cs:\n{boxxl},#2) -- (axis cs:\n{boxxr},#2);             % median
    \draw[line width=0.2mm] (axis cs:#1,#4) -- (axis cs:#1,#6);                                                                           % bar up
    \draw[line width=0.2mm] let \n{whiskerl}={#1-0.025}, \n{whiskerr}={#1+0.025} in (axis cs:\n{whiskerl},#6) -- (axis cs:\n{whiskerr},#6);        % upper quartile
    \draw[line width=0.2mm] (axis cs:#1,#3) -- (axis cs:#1,#5);                                                                           % bar down
    \draw[line width=0.2mm] let \n{whiskerl}={#1-0.025}, \n{whiskerr}={#1+0.025} in (axis cs:\n{whiskerl},#5) -- (axis cs:\n{whiskerr},#5);        % lower quartile
    }
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% Language
\usepackage[english,arabic,main=french]{babel} % Set the language
%\addto\captionsfrench{\def\tablename{Tableau}}
%% Page layout
\usepackage[left=30mm,right=30mm,top=35mm,bottom=35mm]{geometry} % Margines
\usepackage{afterpage}
%% Set the Footer and the Header
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{etoc}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\cfoot{\thepage} % the page number in the foot center
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\hrule height 0pt \vspace{0mm}\hrule height 0pt} % remove plain header rule
}  % reset the page style bcz the arabicore.sty was loaded in the babel

\newcommand{\changefont}{%
    \fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont
}
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\changefont \slshape \rightmark} %section
\fancyhead[LO]{\changefont \slshape \leftmark} %chapter
%\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\changefont \slshape \leftmark} %chapter
\fancyfoot[C]{\changefont \thepage} %footer
% Table
\usepackage{array}      % Fixed length either for each column or for the entire table
\usepackage{tabularx}   % Control the width the entire table
\usepackage{multirow}   % Merged rows and columns
\usepackage{longtable}  % Insert a very long table,
\usepackage{booktabs}   % To thicken table lines


%% Space line
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
%% Customization of captions
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{name=Tableau}            
\captionsetup[figure]{name=Figure}          
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} %list of figures and list of tables are added in the toc
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{soul}
%\usepackage[lined,ruled,vlined,french,algochapter,dotocloa]{algorithm2e} % For writing algorithms
\usepackage{algorithm}% 
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{yhmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{extarrows}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{textcomp, gensymb}
\usepackage{microtype}
\newcommand\blankpage{%
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
    \newpage}
%%  usepackage de usto    
%% Generate Random Text
%\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%%
\usepackage{siunitx}[=v2] 
\usepackage{ifthen}
%% List of Symbols
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
%\makenomenclature

\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{R}}{\item[\textbf{Symboles Romains}]}{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{G}}{\item[\textbf{Symboles Grecs}]}{%
            \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{A}}{\item[\textbf{Acronymes / Abréviations}]}{%
                \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{S}}{\item[\textbf{Autres Symboles}]}{% 
                }% Mathematical symbols > S
            }% Abbreviations        > A
        }% Greek Symbols        > G
    }% Roman Symbols        > R
}

\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{3cm}
%%
\usepackage{pdfpages} % insertion of external multi-page PDF or PS documents

%% New Environment


%\newenvironment{name}[numarg][optarg_default]{begin_def}{end_def}
\newtheorem{exemple}{Exemple}%
\newtheorem{prop}{Propriété}%
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Définition}[chapter]
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remarque}

\newenvironment{dedication}
{
    \cleardoublepage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.66\textwidth}
        \raggedright
    }{\end{minipage}\vspace*{\stretch{3}}\clearpage}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage{tocvsec2} % Used to delete the sections of the appendix from the ToC
\usepackage{pifont}  % More styles for bullets
\usepackage{bm}      % Access bold math symbols
%% Referring to Figure and Table in the text (you can use the classical way)
\begin{comment}
  \newcommand{\fig}[1]{Figure.~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\tab}[1]{Tableau.~\ref{#1}}  
\end{comment}

%%

\hypersetup{
    final=true,
    plainpages=false,
    pdfstartview=FitV,
    pdftoolbar=true,
    pdfmenubar=true,
    bookmarksopen=true,
    bookmarksnumbered=true,
    breaklinks=true,
    linktocpage,
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue,
    anchorcolor=black
}
%% Solve the problem with inserting the symbols \times and \omega when using arabicin the babel
\begin{comment}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\timesr}{\fontfamily{artimes}\selectfont}
\let\times\relax
\DeclareMathSymbol{\times}{\mathbin}{symbols}{"02}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\omegar}{\fontfamily{aromega}\selectfont}
\let\omega\relax
\DeclareMathSymbol{\momega}{\mathord}{letters}{"21}
\end{comment}

thesis.tex
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%thesis by C. Has%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report} 
\input{Preamble/preamble}
\begin{document}
    \dominitoc
    \pagenumbering{gobble}  
    \include{Preliminary-pages/title}
    \include{Preliminary-pages/dedication}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \include{Preliminary-pages/acknowledgements}
    \include{Preliminary-pages/abstract}
    
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \tableofcontents
    \clearpage
    \newpage

    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \cleardoublepage
    \listoffigures
    \cleardoublepage
        
    \listoftables
    \cleardoublepage
    \listofalgorithms
    \adjustmtc[6]
    \cleardoublepage  
    %\markboth{\MakeUppercase\nomname}{\MakeUppercase\nomname}
    %\printnomenclature
    \clearpage
    \newpage
    %-----------------------
    \pagenumbering{arabic}  
    \include{Main-pages/Introduction}
    %\include{Main-pages/Chapter1}
    %\include{Main-pages/Chapter2}  
    %\include{Main-pages/Chapter3}  
    \include{Main-pages/Chapter4}   
    %\include{Main-pages/Chapter5}  
    \include{Main-pages/Chapter6}   
    %\include{Main-pages/Chapter7}  
    %\include{Main-pages/Chapter8}
    \include{Main-pages/Conclusion}
    \onehalfspacing 
    \bibliographystyle{unsrt}   
    \bibliography{Main-pages/mybib}
    \clearpage
    \newpage
    %% backmatter   
    \pagenumbering{Alph}
    %% \begin{appendices}
    %% Appendix Configuration
    \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
    \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
    \renewcommand\thefigure{\thechapter.\arabic{figure}} 
    \renewcommand\thetable{\thechapter.\arabic{table}}  
\end{document}


I try to hide \usepackage{subfigure} and put \usepackage{subcaption} but still give me errors.

Please note that the language used on this site is English. If you prefer to ask your latex questions in French, you can post them at https://texnique.fr/osqa/

Ok thanks i will translate this question in english

If I puzzle together your code fragments and replace all the files I don't have with some simple dummy text, I can compile it just fine. Can you make a [mre] which allows us to reproduce the problem. Keep in mind that we don't have your external files.
